# ehcache program not running

Tags: java, ehcache, terracotta

I am new to `EHcache`. I recently installed `EHcache-2.6.0` on my `Ubuntu 12.04` system. I have been trying to run a simple cache put,get program in java, but it is giving me following error:
 `We couldn't load configuration data from the server at 'localhost:9510'; retrying. (Error: Connection refused.)`
Can anybody please help me to fix this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ehcache when used as a single-JVM cache does not need to connect to a remote server.

So you should begin by coding a simple ehcahe (many documentation can be found on Google).
When your single-JVM works, move to a distributed one.

Edit :
here are some simple code examples : http://ehcache.org/documentation/code-samples

Quickly :

- create a ehcache.xml containing the config of your caches.
- Instanciate one CacheManager.
- Use the CacheManager to retrieve one Cache.
- Use this Cache to do put, get, etc...

Comment: I am trying simple programs. I also tried [this program](http://sensorapp.net/?p=74) but error is the same. I am not getting whats wrong. Could you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Add you fulls tackTrace with the error. Also, are you sure to use the correct EhCache ? and the latest version ? Use http://ehcache.org/downloads/destination?name=ehcache-2.6.0-distribution.tar.gz&bucket=tcdistributions&file=ehcache-2.6.0-distribution.tar.gz and only this one (no other module).